# Advanced variable behavior in the pom.xml?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Is this possible to do advanced action with the variable in the pom? something like:

```
<properties>
  <myVar>A,B,C</myBar>
</properties>
... 
<plugin> 
  <configuration> 
    <skip>${myVar contains project.build.finalName}</skip>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: For what purpose is such thing needed? Can you describe the exact problem you have including the pom files etc.

Comment: I  have a multi module project. They all use the same plugin the same way, except for one propertie who is at true for some module and false for others modules.

Comment: Please show examples of the pom file or best would be a link to a project on github or similar ...